# Tools that show names of unicode characters

Tags: debugging, unicode

While debugging a Unicode-related problem a few months back, I used an extremely helpful online tool that produced the output pasted at the bottom of this q. I now need it again but cannot for the life of me find it despite 45 mins. with Google.  A pointer to the tool, or something close, would be very much appreciated. (Note that I specifically want to be able to look up many characters at once, and have the results stacked vertically.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many such sites that you can find with Google (search for unicode codepoint lookup).  One that will provide what you're looking for is http://unicodelookup.com/

With an input such as `Accents áéíóúü`, you get the following output:

[image]

See: http://unicodelookup.com/#Accents áéíóúü/1

Comment: That was one of the first sites I hit, but e.g. [http://unicodelookup.com/#ろっくふぃるだむ/1](http://unicodelookup.com/#ろっくふぃるだむ/1)  hangs...

Answer (score 0):

Python has a module called [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) that can be used to look up the name of any codepoint.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u200e')
'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK'

>>> for ch in u'\u200elasts.boats.cure':
    print ch, ' %04x ' % ord(ch), unicodedata.name(ch)

‎  200e  LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
l  006c  LATIN SMALL LETTER L
a  0061  LATIN SMALL LETTER A
s  0073  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
t  0074  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
s  0073  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
.  002e  FULL STOP
b  0062  LATIN SMALL LETTER B
o  006f  LATIN SMALL LETTER O
a  0061  LATIN SMALL LETTER A
t  0074  LATIN SMALL LETTER T
s  0073  LATIN SMALL LETTER S
.  002e  FULL STOP
c  0063  LATIN SMALL LETTER C
u  0075  LATIN SMALL LETTER U
r  0072  LATIN SMALL LETTER R
e  0065  LATIN SMALL LETTER E
```